# INVALID_URL error with nextjs 13 and next-auth

Tags: iis, next.js, next-auth

I am trying to setup a new project using nextjs 13 with the new app directory.
So far it looks quite good but I am getting this **INVALID_URL** error when trying to access the next auth signing route.

This is my route.js file:

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth/next';
import Auth0Provider from 'next-auth/providers/auth0';

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    Auth0Provider({
      clientId: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
      issuer: process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account, profile }) {
      // Persist the OAuth access_token and or the user id to the token right after signin
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
        token.id = profile.id;
        token.roles = profile['https://lager.meg-transport.de/roles'];
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      return {
        ...session?.user,
        roles: token?.roles,
      };
    },
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

This the server.js file:
[server.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjM8P.png)

This is the error I get:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJA1F.jpg)

This is my project structure:
[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNv94.png)

When I run the site locally via yarn build and yarn start it works but after deploying it to an IIS I get this error. It seem like the routes are not created correctly or something like this.
I was expecting it to work the same locally as on the server.

EDIT:

For me the final solution was to change to server.js to the following:

```
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { parse } = require('url');
const next = require('next');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
// when using middleware `hostname` and `port` must be provided below
const app = next({ dev, hostname, port });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer(async (req, res) => {
    try {
      // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
      // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
      const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
      const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl;

      if (pathname === '/a') {
        await app.render(req, res, '/a', query);
      } else if (pathname === '/b') {
        await app.render(req, res, '/b', query);
      } else {
        await handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error occurred handling', req.url, err);
      res.statusCode = 500;
      res.end('internal server error');
    }
  }).listen(port, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`);
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Luke, it would be better if you left your question as it was and posted an answer.  This site is about questions and answers.

Answer (score 4):

in your .env file use just need to add the NEXTAUTH_URL if you are on the localhost just put this

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

if your website is deployed put your website url

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=yourwebsitedomain
```

and restart your app after this and it should works fine and error gone

[image]

Comment: I already have this in my env file.

Comment: so maybe it is more of an IIS issue?

Comment: Solved it, I had to change my server.js a little bit

Comment: Good, You can write how you solve it as an answer of your question to help other people having the same issue